# How did the differences between the meanings of priceless and worthless come to be?

Tags: meaning

The two have opposite meanings yet the prefixes are almost synonyms.

Comment: No, the prefixes, *price* and *worth* are not almost synonyms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the 1590s, *priceless* took on its modern meaning of *having a value **beyond** price*.

This makes sense because if I said to you,

> "This object has no price."

the implication is that the object has no price because it is not for sale, and it is not for sale because I cannot put a price on something so important or meaningful.

But, if I said to you,

> "This object has no worth."

the implication is that the object has no value, the object has zero significance or meaning to me.

In short, *price* and *worth* are not in fact synonymous. Therefore, *price-less* (without price) and *worth-less* (without worth) are not synonymous, either.

([Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=priceless))

Comment: Price and worth are almost synonyms. Price- value and worth-value

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries Online [defines](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/price) _price_ as "the amount of money expected, required, or given in payment for something." _Worth_ is [defined](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/worth) as "the value equivalent to that of someone or something under consideration; the level at which someone or something deserves to be valued or rated." One is a tangible measure of money, the other an intangible measure of value.

Comment: @Goldname in English, price and worth are not almost synonyms.

Comment: While I agree that the two quoted sentences have the implications you say _now_, I strongly suspect that that's because of the influence of the current meanings of "_priceless_" and "_worthless_". _That they have those implications now_ doesn't explain how they _came_ to have them. Also, the meanings in both "_What's it worth?_" and "_What is it's price_" are almost identical.